# LoRa point-to-point limitations

Tags: raspberry-pi, communication, lora

I want to set up a point-to-point communication link between two Raspberry Pi using LoRa.

I know for lorawan there is (at least in Europe, where I live) a duty cycle limitation so the nodes can transmit only for an average of 30 seconds uplink time on air, per day, per device.

Is this valid also for point-to-point lora communications? Because my sender keeps on sending.

I am using the code provided [here](http://wiki.dragino.com/index.php?title=Lora/GPS_HAT#Example3_--_Two_RPI_use_LoRa_to_transmit).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is also valid for your LoRa application, since it is emitting radio waves. You can look up limits for europe for specific frequency bands in the [ERC Recommendation 70-03](http://www.efis.dk/reports/ReportDownloader?reportid=2) (page 7). In the ERC Recommendation 70-03 on page 42 you can then look up which of the frequecny bands are allowed for each country.

### Example

Let's say you live in Germany and you want to use frequency 869,400 MHz to 869,650 MHz (this frequency band is called **h1.6**):

[image]

A quick lookup in the ERC Recommendation 70-03 page 39 shows that this band **is** allowed to be used in Germany:

[image]

Further this specific band allows you to use 10% time-on-air (duty-cycle) for your transmitter. This basically means you are allowed to transmit 1 second and are obligated to pause 9 seconds after that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Thus, even if I am not using any existing LoRa network (namely I am creating my own LoRa network) I still have to follow the duty-cycle limitations?

Comment: @clfmaris Yes, **especially** then you are obligated to respect duty-cycles. Annoying, but that's how it works. Otherwise there would be anarchism in frequency distribution. Those guidelines are completely independent from the application you use (LoRa, or WiFI, or GSM, ...)